# Add sidebar items and names (<li>) dynamically based on json var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sidebar (`ul`) where I want to append children dynamically based upon the number of items stored in a `containerType` variable which is a jQuery cookie stored (different number of items for each user).

What I do right now is (when the window loads):

```
var containerTypes = JSON.parse($.cookie('containerTypes')); //Here are all container types this customer has
```

Then:

```
for (var i=0; i < containerTypes.length; i++){
    var obj = containerTypes[i];
    $('<li class="accordion-group"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" 
    data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#side-nav" href="#stats-collapse">
    <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> <span class="name" id="tmpValue"></span></a></li>'
    ).appendTo(".side-nav");
    document.getElementById("tmpValue").innerHTML=obj;
}
```

Problem is that by referring to the same <span id "tmpValue"> the last item is always gonna replace the top one.

How can i fix this problem? I thought to use `document.write` to write the `obj` but I cannot get it to work (I'm a newbie in js/jquery) and I read is not good practice.

I hope someone can help me before I "lose it" :D

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for (var i=0; i < containerTypes.length; i++){
    var obj = containerTypes[i];
    $('<li class="accordion-group"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#side-nav" href="#stats-collapse"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> <span class="name">' + obj + '</span></a></li>').appendTo(".side-nav");
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^current container---------------------------
}
```

This should work, but a better, more-readable, way of doing this would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < containerTypes.length; i++) {
    var obj = containerTypes[i];
    var liTag = $('<li>').addClass('accordion-group').appendTo('#side-nav');
    var aTag = $('<a>').addClass('accordion-toggle').addClass('collapsed').attr({
        'data-toggle': 'collapse',
        'data-parent': '#side-nav',
        'href': '#stats-collapse'
    }).appendTo(liTag);
    var spanTag = $('<span>').addClass('name').text(obj).appendTo(aTag);
}
```

Comment: LOL, what an idiot I am! I did try to escape the variable but didn't work (must have been a typo) so I discarded that idea. Nonetheless, thank you very much!! You came first so you get the correct answer. –

Answer (score 1):

** Jquery **

```
for (var i=0; i < containerTypes.length; i++){
    $('<li class="accordion-group"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" 
    data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#side-nav" href="#stats-collapse">
    <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> <span class="name" id="tmpValue">'+containerTypes[i]+'</span></a></li>'
    ).appendTo(".side-nav");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use this:

```
for (var i=0; i < containerTypes.length; i++){
var obj = containerTypes[i];
$('<li class="accordion-group"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" 
data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#side-nav" href="#stats-collapse">
<i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> <span class="name" id="tmpValue">'+obj+'</span></a></li>'
).appendTo(".side-nav"); ////--------add obj here-----------------^^^
}
```